# Is there a Stokes-like theorem for gradient of a vector?

Tags: calculus, tensors, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem, gradient-flows

Cosidering the usual central field in physics:

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{V}=\frac{\hat{r}}{\mathbf{r}^2}.
\end{equation}

I can get that divergence and curl (and therefore vorticity) are zero when $r\neq0$, and that divergence is $4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r})$ using divergence definition:

\begin{equation}
    \int \nabla \cdot \mathbf{V} d\mathbf{r}^3=\int\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=4\pi,
\end{equation}

For a sphere centered around $r=0$. Also i can understand why curl is zero as there is a point singularity and not a line one.

However, how can i show how is the **shear** tensor in the presence of the singularity? Is there a sort of generalized integral theorem for the full gradient tensor of a field?

Particulary for this case, the shear tensor can be computed as:

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \sigma_{ij}&=&\left (\delta_{ij}\frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{r}\rvert^3}-\frac{3x_ix_j}{\lvert \mathbf{r}\rvert^5}\right )-\frac{4}{3}\pi\delta(\mathbf{r})\delta_{ij}, \\
\end{eqnarray*}

But I'm not sure how to treat the singularity at $r=0$ for the shear.

I hope i was clear. Thank you so much to everyone for your response!

Comment: With this formulation, the singular shear tensor component $\sigma_{ij}$ is not treated anymore as a function of position $\vec{r}$ but as distribution; the Dirac delta captures the singular part of the distribution and the $||\vec{r}||^{-\alpha}$ terms are to be (implicitly) understood as Cauchy principal values, which are not singular anymore due to the way of principal values are computed (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). This kind of handling are often tacit in physics (unfortunately).

Comment: Interesting response. It is possible to write in this case the exact shear distribution in terms of dirac delta?